# Fix stored xss Vulnerability in objective c code

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this piece of code in my project, but when i did a scan it is reporting a vulnerability of stored xss type.

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: filePath
                                 encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                 error: nil];
[self.webView loadHTMLString: htmlString
              baseURL: [[NSBundlemainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

Can anyone let me know how fix this?